# Why does MacHg tell me it's pushing hundreds of thousands of changesets when my project only had a few revisions?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, machg

[image]

Can anybody explain to me what's going on here? Are there two kinds of 'changesets' in Hg?

I have a big project with a lot of big files, and it was getting sluggish, so I deleted the .Hg folder and started over with a new repo in bitbucket. Or so I thought.

This particular Push should only have 200K or so of added/changed files, so not only do I not know why it's reporting so many changesets being pushed but I also don't know why it's taking so long. (At this rate it'll take an hour.)

When it finally did finish, it said it had pushed 2 changesets in the dialog.

Here's hg log, fwiw:

```
changeset:   3:e21eca3496ea
tag:         tip
user:        Jamie Fristrom <***@gmail.com>
date:        Fri Nov 23 12:58:21 2012 -0800
summary:     Project settings, fixed duplicate buildings, reshadow

changeset:   2:9ecb5aab03c2
user:        Jamie Fristrom <***@gmail.com>
date:        Thu Nov 22 21:59:09 2012 -0800
summary:     Fresh new repo

changeset:   1:5b95e18a6377
user:        Jamie Fristrom <***@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Nov 20 17:20:02 2012 -0800
summary:     Fresh new repo

changeset:   0:e2ad59f1136e
user:        Jamie Fristrom <***@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Nov 20 17:03:36 2012 -0800
summary:     initialize repository
```

Could this have something to do with the way BitBucket works? I have a bunch of repos in BitBucket.

Comment: Can you show `hg log` for this repo (revs 2-3 looks very suspicious by description) and `hg outgoing` may help also

Comment: Checkin 0 was the empty BitBucket repo, 1 was the first big checkin, 2 was me forgetting to change the comment.

Comment: Maybe MacHg employs some kind of caching if it thinks it already knows the repository. Either way, you should probably file a bug report at the MacHg project.

Comment: It may be calculating a changeset per file rather than per revision.